# Input number in java input console

Tags: java

I am novice in programming. I have a code. There is one problem. I write number in to a console, but I have nothing in output. The program returns nothing in output console.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new         
InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String snumber = reader.readLine();
      int number = Integer.parseInt(snumber);

      if (number > 0)
      number = number * 2;
      else
      number = number + 1;
      System.out.Println(number);
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you are not displaying anything in the output. You need to do `System.out.println(number);`

Comment: When you’ve found the answer, don’t correct the question, rather either accept the most useful answer or write your own answer with the corrected code. For the future reader, a question where the problem is no longer present won’t make sense. So please.

Comment: Even the "correction" is wrong.  Java is case sensitive.  It should be "println", not "Println".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print something in java, you need to actually call the function that would print to the standard output. 
In other words, you need to use `System.out.print(What_you_want_to_print)`

To see the output for your code, you need to adjust your code as follows:

```
import java.io.*;  
    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new         
            InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String snumber = reader.readLine();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(snumber);
            if (number > 0)
              number = number * 2;
            else
              number = number + 1;
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
```